# How to show another html page with servlet?

Tags: java, html, web, servlets

this is my first time with Java's servlet (and JSP) programming and right now I have a doubt. Imagine that I'm building an online shop with a login page (let's suppose is the starting page) and maybe a shopping page (the "second" one). My servlet contains the code for autenticate the users and if the user is correct the servlet should shows the shopping catalog. My answer is, what's the best method for doing this? This is my servlet code (doGet) now:

nb: userName and password come from the login page...

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body bgcolor = 'green'>");
    out.println("<br>" + "Hello " + "  " + userName + "<br> LOGGED IN!" + "<br>");
    out.println("Your password is : " + "  " + password + "<br>");
    
    if(userName.equals("some_correct_user")) {
        out.println("<p>Login correct </p>");
        response.sendRedirect("/FirstServletExercise/shoppingPage.html");
    }
    else {
        out.println("<p>Access denied</p>");
        
    }
```

I know it's very simple but is just the concept: it's correct to use "sendRedirect" to display another different page, or I have to upgrade the content of the first page? And how I can do this? Hope I have explained myself well.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jetty-11 Server standalone/embedded mode. And here is how the Login Servlet looks like.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginServlet.class);

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.debug("LoginServlet {} userPrincipal: {}", req.getServletPath(), req.getUserPrincipal());
        Map<String, String[]> p = req.getParameterMap();

        p.forEach((k, v) -> {
            log.debug("{} {}", k, v);
        });

        String un = (p.get("j_username") != null) ? p.get("j_username")[0] : null;
        String up = (p.get("j_password") != null) ? p.get("j_password")[0] : null;

        try {
            if (un != null && up != null) {
                req.logout();
                req.login(un, up);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("AuthenticationException: ", e);
        }

        log.debug("{} userPrincipal: {}", req.getServletPath(), req.getUserPrincipal());       
        boolean isAuth = (req.getUserPrincipal() == null) ? false : true;

        log.debug("isAuth: {}", isAuth);
        resp.setContentType("text/html");

        if (isAuth) {
            /** Session Management */
            HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("user", req.getUserPrincipal().getName());
            // setting session to expiry in 30 mins
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30 * 60);
            log.debug("sessionId: {} ", req.getSession().getId());

            /** Cookie Management */
            Cookie loginCookie = new Cookie("user", req.getUserPrincipal().getName());
            loginCookie.setMaxAge(30 * 60);
            resp.addCookie(loginCookie);
            
            /** Login Success - so display the Home Page */
            resp.sendRedirect("./index.html");
        } else {
            Cookie loginCookie = new Cookie("user", "unknownUser");
            loginCookie.setMaxAge(0);
            loginCookie.setPath("/");
            resp.addCookie(loginCookie);
            req.getRequestDispatcher("./login.html").forward(req, resp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```